# Jenkins maven release -- How can I access the tag URL in a post-build task?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I need to be able to access the tag URL that is created (the developerConnection) after a maven release.

I can access the MVN_RELEASE_VERSION, but some of our dev teams just use that as the tag version, and some teams prepend the artifactId, and I really have no way in Jenkins of knowing which projects use which mechanism, so I can't assume that the URL would or wouldn't have the artifactId included.

There doesn't seem to be a definitive list of which variables are available from the release plugin, but does anyone know of a variable I could use to capture this information?

Comment: May I ask why do you need that URL ?

Comment: I am working on a release system for a large enterprise, and when Jenkins runs a release it will be making a REST call over to our release system with the groupID, artifactID, version and tagURL. This will let developers log into the release system and just choose what they want pushed to whichever environment.

Comment: Sounds great. Maybe I misunderstand a thing but wouldn't it be enough to have groupId, artifactId and version to identify the artifact in your repository management system and select it from there? The tagURL is related to the version control? I would deploy from the repository manager. Apart from that I would make a corporate pom file which enforces everyone to use the same approach and don't use different one (but that might be another story)...

Comment: We do a few things other than just deploying the artifacts (which we pull from Archiva), like run liquibase against the database. There are also a few configuration things that we need as well, so we do actually pull the project from version control at deploy time.

Comment: What about picking up the pom which has been created during the release (groupId, artifactId, version) from repo (Archiva) which contains the final tagURL? Wouldn't that be a solution?

Comment: What I've ended up on at the moment is grabbing the workspace and the build number from the Jenkins properties, building the path to the log file for that build, then parsing the new tag URL out of the log file. Not pretty, but it's working very well.